# When plotting a 3D Graphic, how to define the angle it will show?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I know I can after the plot is done, to rotate it with my mouse to the desired angle. Now, I'd like to know how to do the same through code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second look your title involves 3d rotation. For that you can use [ViewPoint](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ViewPoint.html). The example under the applications tab seems to be what you are looking for.

You can use the [ImageRotate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageRotate.html) function.

```
ImageRotate@Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}] (*rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise*)
ImageRotate[Plot[x, {x, 0, 10}], phi]  (*rotate phi degrees counterclockwise*)
```

Answer (score 2):

The 3D view is most conveniently defined through the parameters `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical` (There are additional options: `ViewCenter`, `ViewVector`, and `ViewAngle`, but it usually suffices to leave them on `Automatic`).

So you can do for example

```
Plot3D[Cos[x^2 + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ViewPoint -> {3, 2, 1}]
```

To get good values for `ViewPoint`, etc. I define a function `Get3DView` as

```
Get3DView[gfx_] := 
  Options[Unevaluated[gfx], {ViewCenter, ViewVector, ViewVertical, ViewPoint}]
```

Then you just copy your graphics into `Get3DView` to get your options:

```
plotpar = Get3DView[<your graphics pasted here>]
```

After this you can put your `plotpar` as options for new plot commands (note the Evaluate):

```
Plot3D[Cos[x^2 + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Evaluate@plotpar]
```